# php redirect to a page

Tags: php, redirect

Hello everyone i am trying to write a small addon for my script this is php code :

```
 <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header('Location: /members');
} else {
    echo '<table width="40%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
  <tr align="center" valign="top"> 
    <td bgcolor="#99CC00" class="thinbord"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>قسمت ورود کاربران</strong></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#EEF7FF"> 
    <td class="thinbord"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <form action="/members/" method="post">
          <tr> 
            <td height="25" align="center" valign="bottom" class="boxtext"><strong>email :</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="100"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><strong>پسورد:</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><input type="password" name="passwd" size="20" maxlength="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><input type="hidden" name="form" value="sent" > 
              <input name="submit" type="submit" value="login" ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><a href="/lost.php<? if ($ref) {echo("?ref=$ref"); }?>">lost your pass click here</a>
              <br>please check your spam</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td align="center" class="boxtext"><a href="/signup.php<? if ($ref) {echo("?ref=$ref"); }?>">sign up</a></td>
          </tr>
        </form>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>';
}?>
```

Its show even session uid available the script redirect the page to members and if it not available script show a table for login
The session start before i go this page on my index but its not work and not redirect the page to members.

Comment: have you included `session_start()` in the script. You have to add `session_start()`  in each and every script when dealing with sessions.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) and post the dumped answer here

Answer (score 0):

I think this statement require something `header('Location: /members');`

```
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

php.net say like that

The header string.
There are two special-case header calls. The first is a header that starts with the string "HTTP/" (case is not significant), which will be used to figure out the HTTP status code to send. For example, if you have configured Apache to use a PHP script to handle requests for missing files (using the ErrorDocument directive), you may want to make sure that your script generates the proper status code. 
The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

So, I think you require `http://` on your code.

let do like that  `header('Location: http://www.google.com/');`.So, if you redirect to google, code is correct. If not, you have to change something.

Comment: let do like that http://www.google.com in header.So, if you redirect to google, code is correct. If not, you have to change something.